# I am getting error while I'm creating game with Ursina(python). How can I fix it?

Tags: python, game-engine, game-development, attributeerror, ursina

I'm creating FPS game with Ursina Engine (python). But I started to get a error whenever I tried to play it.

I just started coding so I don't know what I should do.

Code:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import *

class Player(Entity):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.controller = FirstPersonController(**kwargs)
    super().__init__(parent=self.controller)


    self.hand_gun = Entity(parent=self.controller.camera_pivot, scale=0.1, position=Vec3(0.7, -1, 1.5), rotation=Vec3(0, 170, 0), model='gun', Texture='M1911-RIGHT', visible=False)

    self.knife = Entity(parent=self.controller.camera_pivot, scale=0.4, position=Vec3(0.7, -1, 1.5), rotation=Vec3(0, 170, 0), model='knife', Texture='knife', visible=False)

    self.weapons = [self.hand_gun, self.knife]
    self.current_weapon = 0
    self.switch_weapons()


  def switch_weapon(self):
    for i, v in enumerate(self.weapons):
      if i == self.current_weapon:
        v.visible = True
      
      else:
        v.visible = False
  
  def input(self, key):
    try:
      self.current_weapon = int(key) - 1
      self.switch_weapon()
    except ValueError:
      pass

    if key == 'scroll up':
      self.current_weapon = (self.current_weapon + 1) % len(self.weapons)
      self.switch_weapon()

    if key == 'scroll down':
      self.current_weapon = (self.current_weapon - 1) % len(self.weapons)
      self.switch_weapon()

    if key == 'left_mouse_down' and self.current_weapon == 0:
      Bullet(model='sphere', color=color.black, scale=0.2, position=self.controller.camera_pivot.world_position, rotation=self.controller.camera_pivot.world_rotation)


  def update(self):
    self.controller.camera_pivot.y = 2 - held_keys['left control']


class Bullet(Entity):
  def __init__(self, speed=50, lifetime = 10, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.speed = speed
    self.lifetime = lifetime
    self.start = time.time()


  def update(self):
    ray = raycast(self.world_position, self.forward, distance=self.speed*time.dt)
    if not ray.hit and time.time() - self.start < self.lifetime:
      self.world_position += self.forward * self.speed * time.daylight

    else:
      destroy(self)


app = Ursina

ground = Entity(model='plane', scale=20, texture='white_cube', texture_scale='mesh')

player = Player(position=(0,10,0))

app.run()
```

It's just small shooting game that I made for learning Ursina Engine

and the error message I got was:

```
package_folder: C:\Users\Yunwoo Chang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ursina
asset_folder: c:\Users\Yunwoo Chang\Desktop\Tetris\Ursina Engine
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.__del__ at 0x000001E55A5129E0>        
Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "C:\Users\Yunwoo Chang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 185, in __del__    del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "c:\Users\Yunwoo Chang\Desktop\Tetris\Ursina Engine\03 - Weapons.py", line 71, in <module>
    player = Player(position=(0,10,0)) 
  File "c:\Users\Yunwoo Chang\Desktop\Tetris\Ursina Engine\03 - Weapons.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.controller = FirstPersonController(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yunwoo Chang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ursina\prefabs\first_person_controller.py", line 32, in __init__
    ray = raycast(self.world_position+(0,self.height,0), self.down, ignore=(self,))
  File "C:\Users\Yunwoo Chang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ursina\entity.py", line 433, in world_position
    return Vec3(self.get_position(render))
NameError: name 'render' is not defined
```

How can I fix it?

I think it's some kind of attribute error but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate Ursina with `app = Ursina()` before instantiating Entities. You're missing the `()`.

Comment: I changed that, but I still get error

Comment: The same error or a different one? You've also misspelled `self.switch_weapon()`, as `self.switch_weapons()` on line 16.

Comment: I get different error. This time, I get error " line 74, in <module>
    player = Player(position=(0,10,0))
  File "c:\Users\Yunwoo 
Chang\Desktop\Tetris\Ursina Engine\03 - Weapons.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.switch_weapons()
AttributeError: 'Player' object has 
no attribute 'switch_weapons'  "

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in my comment above, you've also misspelled `self.switch_weapon()`, as `self.switch_weapons()` on line 16

Comment: Or 18. Your error message literally says what's wrong, I'm sure you can fix it.